# Moment generating functions of one variable expressed in terms of another

Tags: probability

Suppose that we do not know the distribution of $X_i$. We do know that  $X_1, ..., X_n$ is an iid random variable with $E(X_i) = \mu$; and $Var(X_i) = \sigma^2$.

Let $Y_i = \frac{X_i- \mu }{\sigma}$ and $Z_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum Y_i $

Express the MGF of $Z_n$ in terms of $Y_i$.

What happens to the distribution of $Z_n$> when $n$ approaches infinity?

My solution:

Sorry that I'm quite lost with this question. Since $X$ is i.i.d, it means that I can find $M_y(t)$. This means that $M_y(t) = e^\frac{\mu t}{\sigma}M_x(\frac{t}{\sigma})$.

I also know that since $X$ is i.i.d, any linear combination is also i.i.d. Hence, $Y$ is i.i.d as well.

Does it then mean that MGF of $z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(M_y(t))^n ?$

However, I'm unsure of how I should be proceeding on from here since it seems to me that as n approaches infinity, the MGF will approach 0. Hence, it seems like I've gotten something wrong here.

Any form of hints or help is very much appreciated! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

$Ee^{tZ_n}=(Ee^{\frac t {\sqrt n} Y_1})^{n}$ because $Y_i$'s are i.i.d.. Hence $Ee^{tZ_n}=(Ee^{\frac t {\sigma \sqrt n} X_1})^{n} e^{-\mu \frac t {\sqrt n}}$. To find  the limit you have to use CLT. This theorem tells you that the limit is $e^{t^{2}/2}$.